# No se agregan elementos a la lista

Tags: python-3.x

soy novato programando en python y mi duda es la siguiente: Me enviaron a realizar un programa donde el usuario tiene que ingresar palabras, el programa concluye cuando se ingresan 10 palabras o ingresa un string vacio. No se porque no me imprime la lista con las 10 palabras sino solo me imprime la ultima palabra que ingreso.

```
listapalabras=[]
ingresospalabras=str(input('ingrese palabras: '))
listapalabras.append(ingresospalabras)
i=1

while (i<=10) and not(ingresospalabras==''):
    ingresospalabras=str(input('ingrese palabras:'))
    listapalabras=[]
    listapalabras.append(ingresospalabras)
    i+=1

if i==10:
    print(listapalabras)
    exit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que te ocurre es que dentro de `while` estás reinicializando la variable `listapalabras` asignándole una nueva lista vacía: `listapalabras=[]`. Si eliminas esta debe funcionarte.

Por otra parte puede hacer más pequeño el código si en vez de utilizar la variable `i` para saber la cantidad de elementos ingresados utilizas la función `len()` que te permite conocer la longitud de la lista. Por otra parte dices que tu programa debe terminar si se ingresa ina cadena vacía pero solo imprimes la lista si contiene 10 elementos. Yo haría algo como esto:

```
listapalabras=[]

while len(listapalabras) <= 10:
    ingresospalabras=str(input('ingrese palabras:'))
    if ingresopalabras == '':
        break
    listapalabras.append(ingresospalabras)

print(listapalabras)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, por tu explicacion ya me quedo claro en que estaba fallando.

Comment: Me alegro. Un saludo.